# Last UIView in navigation based app is shown on startup

Tags: iphone, uiview, navigation

strange things happen in my iPhone app. Since a not defined point in time when I start my navigation based app (it doesn't matter if in simulator or on the device) the last UIView (the one that the user reaches last) is shown on startup. After the app is loaded it switches automatically to the RootViewController's view. It's like the last view does the job of a splash screen.

I'm a little bit confused. Did somebody experience the same thing and maybe got the definite hint for a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you showing your root view controller when the application is activated (i.e. in applicationWillResignActive or applicationDidEnterBackground in your app delegate)? Is this running on iOS4? Does it happen every time you press the home button, then 'launch' your app again? I could have a guess at the problem, but it would be best if you could answer those questions and provide a little detail/code, first.

Comment: thanks danny, as you see in my answer below the solution to the problem was easy and the problem itself was a stupid one. as i was using the debugger to check when the last uiview is actually loaded, I recognized that this never happened... sad but true, the problem was me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, SOLVED: It's a pretty good idea to delete a "Default.png" with a screenshot of the last UIView from the Resource folder. No UIView was actually loaded, just the image.... damn it. what a stupid thing and as often, the problem was sitting in front of the screen.